# How does background-position: x% work with background-image?

Tags: css, background, background-image, linear-gradients

## Idea

I'm making animation with `background-image: linear-gradient` but sadly, CSS  can not animate gradient propertive. So i come up with `background-postion` solution. The idea is creating a `background-image` with 3x size of the element and move the `background-postion` during the trasition.

## Problem

To set the `background-position` i can use `px` or `%` but they work really different. Please look at the example below

```js
let elementPixel = document.getElementById('background-pixel');
let elementPercent = document.getElementById('background-percent');
let inputPixel = document.getElementById('range-pixel');
let inputPercent = document.getElementById('range-percent');
let labelPixel = document.getElementById('label-pixel');
let labelPercent = document.getElementById('label-percent');

inputPixel.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
  elementPixel.style.backgroundPosition = `0 ${inputPixel.value}px`;
  labelPixel.innerHTML = `background-position: ${inputPixel.value}px`
})
inputPercent.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
  elementPercent.style.backgroundPosition = `0 ${inputPercent.value}%`;
  labelPercent.innerHTML = `background-position: ${inputPercent.value}%`
})
```

```css
.background-animateable {
  margin: 50px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, white 0%, red 32.9%, yellow 33%, yellow 34%, red 34.1%, green 65.9%, yellow 66%, yellow 67%, green 67.1%, blue 100%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.wrapper1 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center
}

.wrapper2 {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%
}

.wrapper2 .background-animateable {
  background-size: 100% 300%;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.parent input {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#background-pixel {
  background-position: 0 0px;
}

#background-percent {
  background-position: 0 0%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper1">
  <div class="background-animateable"> </div>
  &larr;Origin background look like this
</div>

<div class="wrapper2">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="background-animateable" id="background-pixel"></div>
    <label id="label-pixel">background-position: 0 0px</label>
    <input type="range" id="range-pixel" name="volume" min="-600" value="0" max="600" />
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="background-animateable" id="background-percent"></div>
    <label id="label-percent">background-position: 0 0%</label>
    <input type="range" id="range-percent" name="volume" min="-200" value="0" max="200" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Just play with the snipet. 
If we set `background-postion` in `px`, negative value means background will stay higher than the element and we can see other part of `background-image`, positive value will make background lower than element so we will see the blank `background-color`. It's deserved behavior. 
When we set `background-postion` in `%`, the first thing come in my head is it will be same as 'px' and the distance will be base on background size. But, no! If we want to see `33%->66%` of the background image we need to set **`background-position: 0 50%`** meanwhile the value in `px` is **`background-position: 0 -200px`**. What's happen? It's opposite about sign, and about the value `200px ~ 33.33%` height of `background-image` not `50%`. Hmm, it's really confuse here.

## Question

So the question is: How does `background-postion: ...%` work with `background-image`?
Note that: If we change `linear-gradient` with image `url`, the behavior will bee still the same

Comment: Unrelated, but also possible: You could use `transform: translate` in a container with `overflow: hidden` to just move around the gradient-image.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 Yeah. Thanks. It's will get better performance